# Exponential regression residual check

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, exponential-distribution, residuals

If you have an exponential regression of the form `log(y) = b0 + b1x` with predicted equation `ŷ = 10^(b0 + b1x)` and you need to check for hetereoscdasticity (comparing residuals with fitted/actual values) how do you calculate the residuals?

What i do is to get the `log(y)` where my y is the actual/dependent variable, and do the regression and find a `log(y)_pred`. Will the residuals be `log(y) - log(y)_pred` or `y-ŷ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you estimate the model

$\ln(y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \varepsilon_i$

then

$\mathrm{E}(y_i | x_i) \neq \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i}$

For one possible solution see: Duan, N., 1983. Smearing estimate: A nonparametric retransformation method.  *Journal of the American Statistical Association* 78:605-610.

Alternatively, you can (and should) circumvent the entire problem by modeling $\ln(\mathrm{E}(y_i))$ instead of $\mathrm{E}(\ln(y_i))$, that is use a log link function. See for example:

- Chapter 18 of Jeffrey M. Wooldridge (2010) Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data, Second Edition. MIT Press. or
- Nicholas J. Cox, Jeff Warburton, Alona Armstrong, Victoria J. Holliday (2007) "Fitting concentration and load rating curves with generalized linear models" Earth Surface Processes and Landforms, 33(1):25--39. DOI: [10.1002/esp.1523](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/esp.1523)